# Jackson - Json string to Java List of class

Tags: java, jackson

I am trying to map a JSON string to a Java class using Jackson.

```
public class ChartData {
    List<String> xAxis=new ArrayList<String>();
    List<String> yAxis=new ArrayList<String>();
    List<String> zAxis=new ArrayList<String>();
    String type;

    public ChartData() {

    }

    public ChartData(String type, List<String> yAxis, List<String> zAxis) {
        this.type = type;
        this.yAxis = yAxis;
        this.zAxis = zAxis;

    }
```

The code  I tried :

```
List<ChartData> emp = new ArrayList<>();
String o2 ="[{\"type\": \"2\", \"yAxis\": [\"11\"], \"zAxis\": [\"8\"]}, {\"type\": \"3\", 
             \"yAxis\": [\"17\", \"13\", \"12\"], \"zAxis\": [\"14\", \"13\", \"12\"]}]";
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
data= (List<ChartData>) mapper.readValue(o2, ChartData.class);

return data;
```

But, I am getting the following error:

> Can not deserialize instance of com.ChartData out of START_ARRAY token
>   at [Source: [{"type": "2", "yAxis": ["11"], "zAxis": ["8"]}, {"type":
>   "3", "yAxis": ["17", "13", "12"], "zAxis": ["14", "13", "12"]}]; line:
>   1, column: 1]

Where is my mistake?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a specific way to deserialize into list in jackson:

```
List<ChartData> data = mapper.readValue(o2 , new TypeReference<List<ChartData>>(){});
```

In your code you have also type mismatch in the conversion. You are using `mapper.readValue(o2, ChartData.class)` but you are casting it to `List<ChartData>`.

To maintain the basic type conversion (without `TypeReference`) you can deserialize the json into array in the following way:

```
ChartData[] data = mapper.readValue(o2 , ChartData[].class);
```

and afterwards convert it to a list if you need to.